# Correct functions for cleaning and inserting data into database

Tags: php, security, mysqli

Initializing variables:

```
<? php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pword = '';
$dbname = 'mydb';
$tablename = 'userdata';
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pword);
```

Code for function to clean data to be sent to database (where `$variables` is an array which has data which is trimmed, `strip_tags` and `htmlspecialchars`) assuming that we are connected to the database:

```
function cleandbvalues($variables) {
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $variables['firstname']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $variables['lastname']);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $variables['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $variables['password']);
$gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $variables['gender']);
$course = $variables['course'];
$string = implode(",",$course);
$course = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$string);
$comments = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $variables['comments']);
}
```

(Note: The following code is for `variables` array)

```
function clean($data) {
$data = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($data)))); 
return $data;
}

function initialize(){
$var = array();
$var['firstname'] = isset($_POST['firstname']) ? clean($_POST['firstname']) : '';
$var['lastname'] = isset($_POST['lastname']) ? clean($_POST['lastname']) : '';
$var['username'] = isset($_POST['username']) ? clean($_POST['username']) : '';
$var['password'] = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
if(!empty($_POST['gender'])) {                
$var['gender'] = $_POST['gender'];
}  else {
    $var['gender'] = '';
}
//var_dump($_POST[gender]);
if(!empty($_POST['course'])) {               
$var['course'] = $_POST['course'];
} else {
    $var['course'] = '';
}
$var['comments'] = isset($_POST['comments']) ? clean($_POST['comments']) : '';
  return $var;
}

$variables = initialize();
```

Code for function to insert above cleaned data into table:

```
function insertvalues($firstname,$lastname,$username,$password,$gender,$course,$comments) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO userdata 
 (uid,firstname,lastname,username,password,gender,course,comments)
 VALUES ('','$firstname','$lastname','$username','$password','$gender','$string','$comments')";
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pword); 
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";
}


mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Are these the correct functions for cleaning data to be sent to database and inserting the data in database in PHP? I didn't want to use just plain code but wanted to use code inside functions for re-usability,so is it right?

Comment: What do you mean by "is this correct"?  Have you tested it to make sure it does what it should?  We can only review this code if it works as intended.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your code is a bit unclear as to how it actually works (what function is executed when), but I'll try my best to answer anyways.

> Are these the correct functions for cleaning data to be sent to database and inserting the data in database in php?

No, they are not.

**Preventing SQL Injection: General Overview**

- `mysqli_real_escape_string` is meant to be used to escape user input before inserting it into a database (to somewhat sometimes prevent SQL injection).
- `htmlspecialchars` is meant to escape user input before outputting it to the user (to prevent XSS attacks in most cases).

This means that `htmlspecialchars` shouldn't be used for escaping database input at all.

So is `mysqli_real_escape_string` the right solution? **No**, because it is generally not recommended to rely on input escaping. Here is what the [owasp says about escaping input](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_3:_Escaping_All_User_Supplied_Input):

> [input escaping] is frail compared to using parameterized queries and
>   we cannot guarantee it will prevent all SQL Injection in all
>   situations. This technique should only be used, with caution, to
>   retrofit legacy code in a cost effective way. Applications built from
>   scratch, or applications requiring low risk tolerance should be built
>   or re-written using parameterized queries.

[This isn't just a theoretical concern either.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)

So you should use [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) instead. [Not relevant for your code, but in general: you should use prepared statements for all user input, as well as all values that you retrieved from the database which are based on user input (to prevent [second order SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952187/how-do-i-demonstrate-a-second-order-sql-injection))].

**Other**

- in PHP, arguments are [passed by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879/are-php-variables-passed-by-value-or-by-reference) so your `cleandbvalues` function doesn't do anything.
- please use proper formating (indentation, spaces, etc).
- follow general naming conventions (`cleandbvalues` should be `cleanDbValues` or `clean_db_values`, same for `insertvalues`).