# PHP framework building: MySQL Connection and query class

Tags: php, design-patterns, classes, mysqli

I am building a PHP framework and would like to get some feedback on a few different sections of the project so far. I consider myself still a neophyte in PHP so I would like to ask if I'm going about completing these different tasks in an efficient and or correct way.

This section is of the MySQL Connection class I have created for it. So for I have created the basic operations for connecting and querying the database. I have posted below the class code and a script showing how it can be use.

I would like to get feedback on if this is the proper way to create this type of class and an efficient way to complete database querying tasks.

**MySQL Connection Class**

```
class MysqlConnection{
    //Connetion login
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $database;
    private $connection;
    //Query being used
    public $query;
     /**
     * @param String $host - server host
     * @param String $user - username
     * @param String $database - database name
     * @param String $password - username password
     * @return Null
     */
    public function __construct($host,$user,$password,$database){
        if(isset($host,$user,$password,$database)){
            //If parameter supplied
            $this->host = $host;
            $this->user = $user;
            $this->password = $password;
            $this->database = $database;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }
    /**
     * Send query to database
     * 
     * @param String $query - query statment
     * 
     * Note: This allow a query to the DB if
     * the class is going to be used withing a fuction
     * or method
     */
    public function Query($query){
        if(isset($this->connection)){
            if(($this->query = @$this->connection->query($query))){
                return $this->query;  
            }
                return false;

        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }

    public function LastId(){
        return $this->connection->insert_id;
    }

    /**
     * Result
     */
    public function Result($quresults = null){
        if(empty($quresults) && !empty($this->query)){
            return $this->query->fetch_assoc();
        }
        return $quresults->fetch_assoc();
    }
    /**
     * Inserts a new row into the database.
     * 
     * @param Array $data - key column name value data
     * @param String $table - name of DB table
     * @return results on success else mysql error string on failure
     * 
     */
    public function insert($data, $table) {
        $columns = "";
        $values = "";
        foreach ($data as $column => $value) {
            $columns .= ($columns == "") ? "" : ", ";
            $columns .= $column;
            $values .= ($values == "") ? "" : ", ";
            $values .= "'".addslashes($value)."'";
        }
        $sql = "insert into $table ($columns) values ($values)";
        if(isset($this->connection)){
            if(!($this->query = @$this->connection->query($sql))){
                return false;
            }
            return $this->query;
        }else{
            trigger_error('MySQLConnection not opened',E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update a row in DB
     * 
     * @param Array $data - key is the column name and value is data
     * @param String $table - name of table to update row
     * @param string $where - where clause
     */
    public function update($data, $table, $where) {
        if(isset($this->connection)){
            foreach ($data as $column => $value) {
                $sql = "UPDATE $table SET $column = '".addslashes($value)."' WHERE $where";
                if(!@$this->connection->query($sql)){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }else{
            trigger_error('MySQLConnection not opened',E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Select rows from the database
     * 
     * 
     */
    public function select($select = '*',$table, $where) {
        if(isset($this->connection)){
            $sql = "SELECT ".$select." FROM $table WHERE $where";
            if(($result = $this->connection->query($sql))){
                if($result->num_rows > 0){
                    return ($this->query = $result);
                }
                return false;
            }
            return false; 
        }else{
            trigger_error('MySQLConnection not opened',E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete row from
     */
    public function delete($table,$where){
        if(isset($this->connection)){
            $sql = "DELETE FROM ".$table." WHERE ".$where;
            $this->connection->query($sql);
            if($this->connection->affected_rows > 0){
                return true;
            }
            return false; 
        }
    }
    /**
    * Close DB connection
    * 
    * @param void
    * @return void
    */
    public function Close(){
        $this->connection->close();
    }
    /**
     * Open DB connection using parameters given
     * in the construct
     * 
     * @param void
     * @return boolean - TRUE on success else FALSE on failure
     */
    public function Open(){ 
        $this->connection = @new mysqli($this->host,$this->user,$this->password,$this->database);
        //return !!$this->connection->connect_errno;
        if($this->connection->connect_errno){
            return false;
        }else{
             return $this->connection;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Get last DB connection or query error
     * 
     * @param void
     * @return DB connection or query error string
     * 
     * Dev Note: Modify method to allowing opionsel
     * return value
     */
    public function GetError() {
        if(!empty($this->connection->connect_error)){
            return $this->connection->connect_error;
        }elseif(!empty($this->connection->error)){
            return $this->connection->error;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Escape special characters by
     * adding slashes
     * 
     * @param String - string to escape characters
     * @return String - escape string
     */
    public function AddSlashes($string){
        return addslashes($string);
    }

    /**
     * Break an array up into comma seperated value list
     * 
     * @param Array $array - an array or strings
     * @return String of CSV list
     */
    public function PBreak($array){
        if(is_array($array)){
           return implode(',', $string); 
        }
    }
    /**
     * Close open DB connections
     * 
     * @param void
     * @return void
     */
    public function __destruct(){
        if(!empty($this->connection)){
            @$this->connection->close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Script using it's methods**

```
 //Conntect to DB
$dbconnection = $core->CreateCore('mysqlconnection','database','localhost','root','password','dummy');
$dbconnection->Open();
$queryReturn = $dbconnection->Query("SELECT * FROM dummy WHERE num = 1");
echo "<pre>";
//Using Result()
var_dump($dbconnection->Result());
echo "</pre>";
/**
 * equivalent using QuerySelecti
 * 
 * The dummy table columns are
 * num INT, text VARCHAR, other VARCHAR
 */
//Using insert() method
$dbconnection->insert(array('num'=>4,'text'=>'New insert','other'=>'This is a text'),'dummy');
//Using LastId() method
echo "<pre>";
//Using Result()
var_dump($dbconnection->LastId());
echo "</pre>";
//using GetError() method
if(!$dbconnection->GetError()){
    $dbconnection->update(array('num'=>4,'text'=>'Another insert','other'=>'This is NEW text'),'dummy','num = 4');
}
//using select() method
$queryReturn = $dbconnection->select("num, text, other",'dummy','num = 4');
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($dbconnection->Result());
echo "</pre>";
//Using update method
$dbconnection->delete('dummy','num = 4');
//Using close() method
$dbconnection->Close();
```

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: What does your class extend? you have a `parent::__construct();` in the constructor, but the class itself: `class MysqlConnection{` doesn't extend anything. If it extends `mysqli` (as your tags suggest), then don't. Simply don't. Also adhere to the coding standards, and stick to the SOLID principles. and stop using the `@` operator of death

Comment: I forgot to take that line out before posting this question. The class extends an abstract `DatabaseConnection` class that then extends a `System` class that reads default database connect values from am ini file. I have posted a question about the `System` class if you would like to review it.
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/63687/28060
I hope this was a good answer. I can post the code for the `DatabaseConnection` class if you think it would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use early returns to simplify if statements**

This code from the `insert` function:

> ```
>     if(isset($this->connection)){
>         if(($this->query = @$this->connection->query($query))){
>             return $this->query;  
>         }
>             return false;
>
>     }else{
>         return false;
>     }
> ```

Can be rewritten like this:

```
    if(!isset($this->connection)){
        return false;
    }
    if(($this->query = @$this->connection->query($query))){
        return $this->query;  
    }
    return false;
```

You can use this principle in other functions as well (for example for the `isset` check in `update`, `delete` and `select`).

In this case, I would make the setting of `$this->query` more explicit:

```
    if(!isset($this->connection)){
        return false;
    }
    $this->query = @$this->connection->query($query);
    return $this->query;
```

You don't need a separate command to return false, as [`query` returns false on failure](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).

**Further if simplifications**

This from your `select` function:

> ```
>         if(($result = $this->connection->query($sql))){
>             if($result->num_rows > 0){
>                 return ($this->query = $result);
>             }
>             return false;
>         }
>         return false;
> ```

can be collapsed to one if statement:

```
        $result = $this->connection->query($sql);
        if($result && $result->num_rows > 0){
            return ($this->query = $result);
        }
        return false;
```

And this from your `delete` function:

> ```
>         if($this->connection->affected_rows > 0){
>             return true;
>         }
>         return false;
> ```

can be rewritten like this:

```
        return $this->connection->affected_rows > 0;
```

**Result function**

Do you expect a use case where you need to pass a parameter to `Result`? If not, I would remove it, it just complicates your code.

Either way, right now, if I pass null (or nothing), and `$this->query` is empty, `fetch_assoc` will be called on null.

**update function**

Right now, multiple updates can be executed with one call of `update`. If one fails, the rest are not executed. But the previously executed once are not rolled back either.

And the caller doesn't know which statements got executed and which didn't. I think that this might cause problems in the future.

**SQL injection**

`addslashes` does not adequately defend against SQL injections (see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860954/examples-of-sql-injections-through-addslashes), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339844/is-phps-addslashes-vulnerable-to-sql-injection-attack), or [here](http://www.itshacked.com/344/bypassing-php-security-addslashes-while-sql-injection-attacks-is-possible.html)).

See also this answer where I link to more [resources about SQL Injections and prevention](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/62873/49695) of it.

Also, it might be confusing for a future user of your class that some values are escaped while others are not (and thus the escaping is the task of the caller). `$table`, `$columns`, `$column`, `$where`, and of course `$query` are not escaped, while `$value` is.

**Style Guidelines**

- generally, function names should start with a lower-case letter (you can even see it here in the code highlighter: the upper-case functions are rendered the same as the class, while the lower-case functions are not).
- a minor point: try to be consistent with your curly brackets and the spaces around them (`){` vs `) {`).
- be consistent with your indentation.
- be consistent with string concatenation (`FROM $table WHERE $where` vs `FROM ".$table." WHERE ".$where`).
- be consistent with your single- and double-quotes (`"num, text, other"` vs `'dummy'`).

**General Approach**

For me, your example calls:

> ```
> insert(array('num'=>4,'text'=>'New insert','other'=>'This is a text'),'dummy')
> select("num, text, other",'dummy','num = 4')
> ```

are a bit hard to read. You could instead implement a query builder to make them look something like this:

```
new QueryBuilder().select("num", "other").from("dummy").where("num = ?", 4)
```

Note also that the `4` is separate from the sql syntax, thus making it easier to use prepared statements when executing such a query.

For ideas for a querybuilder interface, you could look at existing once, such as [FluentPDO](http://fluentpdo.com/documentation.html) or the [QueryBuilder of Doctrine](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html). You could also take a look at the [source code of FluentPDO](https://github.com/lichtner/fluentpdo/tree/master/FluentPDO) to get some ideas (it's just a couple of files).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now looking it over the `update()` does have that handicap. Also thank you for pointing out the conditions. To be honest I was starting to think there was and excessive amount of `if else` clauses. I will post my updates and if possible would appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to previous answer:

- You shouldn't use `@`, use `try {} catch () {}` instead.
- You shouldn't use `trigger_error`, use exceptions instead.
- You should use statement preparing and argument binding instead of concatenation, this would add another security layer between user and database, and you wouldn't need to use `addslashes` at all.
- You should create interface(for example `DbConnection`) with all your methods and then implement it, this allows extending your library for another databases
- Try to split your class into connection itself, it's state (pattern `State`), query(pattern `Query-Object`) and query builder(pattern `Builder`).
- As additional: try to map objects to tables :)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. splitting the operations into different classes would be the most effective.

Comment: @andrewnite You are always welcome :)